# Find id out of array and addclass

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple forms on one page. I'm trying to iterate through every form I have and find id's (from an array) of childrens and add a class and attribute. I believe my code explains it better then I do.

This is my jQuery code:

```
let ids = ['#date', '#wH', '#note'];

$('form').each(function () {
    ids.forEach(function (value) {
        $(this).find(value).addClass('thisDisabled');
        $(this).find(value).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
    });
})
```

This is the html code:

```html
<form id="note54" action="requests.php" method="post">
    <div class="noteinfo">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2">
            <p><strong><label for="date">Notiz: #26</label></strong>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 datum">
            <input type="date" name="date" id="date" value="2019-09-27" max="2019-09-29">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 zeit">
            <label for="wH">Hours:</label>
            <input type="number" step="0.25" min="0" name="workedTime" id="wH" value="1.50">
            Std.
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 abgerechnet">
            <label for="billed">billed</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="billed" id="billed" value="1">
            <button type="submit" class="fa-bttn fl-r" name="UpdateNote">
                <span><i class="fa fa-save save"></i></span>
            </button>
            <input type="hidden" name="request" value="update-note">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 notecontent">
        <textarea name="notiz" id="note" rows="6">Note</textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

I've expected that from every form the children with matching ids should be disabled, but nothing happens. I have no error messages at all.

Comment: ID must be unique. That's why it's called ID. Use **class**es instead.

Comment: Even if you are right, of course, about unique ID, the ID is unique in each form, so the form.find jquery method should work.

Comment: For me @iguypouf is right, the ID's are unique because they are under the form. So "form#note54 #note" is unique.

Comment: I didnt say your html is correct; posters are right to point this. I just said that formelement.find should work as ID are unique in their parent.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check the scope of $(this); in the second foreach its not your form anymore.

```
let ids = ['#date', '#wH', '#note'];

$('form').each(function () {
    var form = $(this);
    ids.forEach(function (value) {
        form.find(value).addClass('thisDisabled');
        form.find(value).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
    });
})
```

Comment: This works for me! And thanks for the hint with the scope.

Answer (score 2):

Every ID must be an unique at whole page. Use class instead. And you can minimize your code:

```
$( '.date, .wH, .note' ).addClass('thisDisabled').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

Comment: This works to. But as a note, the IDs are unique, because they residate in the form, so "form #note" is unique.

Comment: The id attribute value **must** be unique within the HTML document. Please, read html specification https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp